# How to redirect input and get it back at EOF on Bash-like?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

How to exec a command with first input from a file, and then from stdi ?

I mean, something like `<` redirection, but getting the control back to the user once EOF reached without sending an EOF to the command ?

Comment: Can you update your question with a specific example of the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to limit the scope of the redirection or use a different file descriptor instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply group two commands.

```
{ cat file; cat; } | some_command
```

`some_command` gets first the contents of `file` and then standard input of the script.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify I’ll assume your input file contains "example". Feel free to replace `printf 'example'` with `cat yourfile.txt`.

```
printf "Enter value: "
read variable < <(printf 'example' ; cat)
echo "variable=$variable"
```

`printf 'example'` is just the program of the first part of your input. `cat`, when called with no file, just echoes to stdout what you typed from stdin. In this case `cat` will write to the stdin of `read`.

And if you want to output to the console what you gave as input with the first command, you may play with `tee` and stderr:

```
printf "Enter value: "
read variable < <(printf 'example' | tee >(cat >&2) ; cat)
echo "variable=$variable"
```